# Why <style scoped> is not being parsed

Tags: vue-component

Just getting started with Vue and I can't get the `<style scoped>` to be processed by Vue. It fails to add the the proper attributes keys to my template elements and fails to augment the CSS classes with attribute specificity. It just behaves like "scoped" was not defined. I am not running any kind of build pipeline framework. Do I have to run some pre-processor or transpiler for this to work? I don't get how the Vue framework is even supposed to know which style block should be scoped to what Vue component since I bundle all my styles in one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scoped css is a feature that is provided by using `vue-loader`, you can find the documentation here: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/#what-is-vue-loader

As it is explained there, the scoped css is compiled using webpack. A good way to get started with Vue single file components and all the benefits they bring, is to setup a new vue project using `vue-cli`, you can find the docs here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

Comment: Is there a way to do this without webpack? I have to integrate some new development within an existing legacy project currently in ASP.NET WebForms which uses only server side rendering. Don't think its possible to integrate webpack with this since Vue.js will be mixed in with this older code.

Comment: You should be able to do this with the `compiler-utils` package https://github.com/vuejs/component-compiler-utils I have personally not worked with it yet, but it might be just what you need.

Comment: I see, so you need a pre-processor. Probably not worth the trouble for just scoped styles. Want to keep it simple.